# How do i create a working Template in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the next code for EpaxnseItHome.xaml :

```
<ListBox Name="peopleListBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExpenseDataSource}, XPath=Person}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource nameItemTemplate}">
    </ListBox>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!-- Expense Report Data -->
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ExpenseDataSource" XPath="Expenses">
            <x:XData>
                <Expenses xmlns="">
                    <Person Name="Mike" Department="Legal">
                        <Expense ExpenseType="Lunch" ExpenseAmount="50" />
                        <Expense ExpenseType="Transportation" ExpenseAmount="50" />
                    </Person>
                </Expenses>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
        <!-- Name item template -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="nameItemTemplate">
            <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>            
    </Grid.Resources>
```

The Label have a reference to a template from `<Grid.Resources>` but when starting the app it returns an error that couldn't be find a resource with name "nameItemTemplate". This example is taken from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application?fbclid=IwAR3SO_BtOF1W6IO9Ii9uytpmmwHIpRXl8GXhtlkLGZj6k4k926w2v50aSrc#see-also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it, declaration of a new Template should be made before it is used. So, to solve it I just swapped `<Grid.Resource>...</Grid.Resourse>` with `<ListBox>...<...>`.